# SQL Server Agent Powershell Job Returns Blank

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a PowerShell script:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "PRODUCTION" -Database "DATABASE" -InputFile "E:\DW_Exports\cdd.sql" | Export-Csv "E:\DW_Exports\Pearsonvue\CDD.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

When I run this manually in ISE, works fine, no problems.

However, when I set it up as a SQL Agent job it just returns a blank file. No errors reported, it says it was successful, but all I end up with is a blank file.

I've tried the process with very simple queries (just changing the input file the PowerShell points to), and it works fine. So we can rule out SQL Server Agent access issues to the file location or running PowerShell. It just doesn't work for this specific query.

Whats also odd is that sometimes after I run the job, if I try to run the PowerShell script manually it says I don't have access to the file location unless I delete the blank file, then it works fine again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Next time you get the error about access, use Process Explorer to see which process holds a handle to the file. It's likely to be SQLAgent.exe, but maybe there is an antivirus causing troubles too? What if you remove the piping and use intermediate variables. Write into a log file about each step, see if there's anything funny going on.

Comment: @vonPryz greatly appreciate the comment. I'm quite new to powershell processes, do you have any good sources regarding setting up logging per step?